# Identification of brown butterfly with orange/black/white spots

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

These brown butterflies are very frequent at my place now. Two or three can be found quietly sitting with their wings folded everyday, at different locations. It's a transition period between Autumn and Winter here, West Bengal, India.

What species is this?

Why is it taking shelter inside a house? They don't seem to move much, even during the day I've found one sitting quietly by the window. It wasn't flying off even after being disturbed.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the "Dark Evening Brown" or *Melanitis phedima* possibly *Melanitis phedima bela*:

[image]

[image]

Some further information can be found [here](http://insecta.pro/taxonomy/54255) (image 1) and [here](http://www.ifoundbutterflies.org/sp/736/Melanitis-phedima) (image 2). If you look close at the second image, you can see the spot on the wing.

Why they are coming into the houses is something I can only speculate about, but probably they are either attracted by light or by warmth.

Answer (score 5):

As to your question why they come into the house: Some butterflies survive winter (hibernate) on a dry, cool but frost-free place such as parts of houses that are not heated. In autumn they actively search for such places. I often find them in a wood stack or on the attic. In Europe, examples are *Gonepteryx rhamni*, *Polygonia c-album* and *Inachis io*. I think the latter two belong to the same family as *Melanitis phedima*, so it might try to find a place to hibernate. For more info see https://www.britishbutterflies.co.uk/winter.asp

Comment: Slight wording issue; For these species (ones with a life history that includes hibernation as adults), it's not that they **can** survive winter as adults, it's **how** they survive winter. In most taxa of insects living in temperate regions species survive winter as either eggs, larvae, pupae or adults, or a mixture of hibernation stages.

Comment: @fileunderwater You are absolutely right. Improved that in my answer.

Comment: How long can these butterflies live?